# Why this code giving output 200?

Tags: php, function

Solve this problem please...

```
function abc($a, $b) { 
    echo  $c = $a+$b;
}

echo   0*( abc(10,10)  ); // giving output 200!!!!!
echo "<br />";
echo   6*( abc(10,10)  ); //giving output 200!!!!! 
echo "<br />";
echo   30*( abc(10,10)  ); //giving output 200!!!!!
```

any one who help in this?

Comment: use `return` instead of `echo $c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do is `echo 0 * (echo (10 + 10)).`
With the precedence of the parenthesis, you first `echo 10 + 10 (= 20),` then `echo 0 * (void)` and it seems that void is implicitly cast to `int(0)`, where void is the return of function `abc`, so the output is 200.

`6 * void` and `30 * void = 0` either, so the output is the same.

EDIT: 
This is, step by step, what happens:
Echo 0 * (abc(10 + 10)):

1) Calls abc

2) echoing 10 + 10 (so it outputs 20 at this moment.)

3) returning from abc (it returns void because you don't specify a return value)

4) evaluates 0 * (abc(10 + 10)) = 0 * void = 0 * 0 = 0

5) echoing 0 (so it ouputs 0 right after the 20 from the step 2) ).

The steps for you second and third lines are the same, since 6 * 0 and 30 * 0 equals 0 too.

Comment: I would add as a comment because it is purely my opinion : Here is a nice example of why PhP is a bad programming language : it behaves weirdly and implicitely and it is too permissive

Comment: i still confused with this answer :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use `return` inside a function to `return` the value.

**EXAMPLE 1: ([LINK](https://3v4l.org/MbueG))**

```
function abc($a, $b) { 
    return $a+$b;
}
echo   0*( abc(10,10)  ); // gives output of 0 
echo "<br />";
echo   6*( abc(10,10)  ); // gives output of 120 
echo "<br />";
echo   30*( abc(10,10)  ); // gives output of 600
```

The result will return `200` because the function echos `20` then returns `0`. This will create `20` and `0` side by side looking like `200`, therefore creating the `200` impression.

if I add a space at the end of the echo you will see `20 0 20 0 20 0`.

See **@Krapow**'s answer for more detail.

**EXAMPLE 2: ([LINK](https://3v4l.org/DCloo))**

```
function abc($a, $b) { 
    echo $a+$b." ";
}

echo   0*( abc(10,10)  ); // gives output of 20 0 
echo "<br />";
echo   6*( abc(10,10)  ); // gives output of 20 0 
echo "<br />";
echo   30*( abc(10,10)  ); // gives output of 20 0
```

Comment: @WaleedRaza Krapow's answer is more in detail.

Comment: but then what about 0,6,30?? what the role in this code at multiplication?

Comment: @WaleedRaza It would be 0*0=0 6*0=0 30*0=0 so the become 0.